# MongoDB use $and with $or operator in the same query

Tags: mongodb

Hi I want to set filter to collection on mongodb.

I want to do set filter (Code field startswith "0" or "2") and (FirmId eq to "5186224fdff7421bd4552f7f")

But query result is null. What is wrong?

My mongo query is;

```
db.Customers.find({ "$and" : [{ "FirmId" : ObjectId("5186224fdff7421bd4552f7f") }, { "$or" : [{ "Code" : /^0/ }, { "Code" : /^2/ }] }] })
```

_

```
 {
    $and: [
        {
            "FirmId": ObjectId("5186224fdff7421bd4552f7f")
        },
        {
           "$or": [
                {
                    "Code": /^0/
                },
                {
                    "Code": /^2/
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

or use

```
{
    "FirmId": ObjectId("5186224fdff7421bd4552f7f"),
    "$or": [
        {
            "Code": /^0/
        },
        {
            "Code": /^2/
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Wy are you using $and?

Comment: You shouldn't need `$and` on the top level (it's implicit).

Comment: Add a sample data that you expect to be returned by the query.

Comment: Try this: `{
  "FirmId": ObjectId("5186224fdff7421bd4552f7f"),
  "$or": [
    {
      "Code": /^0/
    },
    {
      "Code": /^2/
    }
  ]
}`

Comment: nothing change use $and or not use $and

Comment: Then your query has a problem finding the documents in question, do you actually have a document that matches this criteria?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be using either `$and` nor `$or` here.

`{ FirmId: ObjectId("xxx"), Code:/^[02]/ }`

If you don't get any results then possibly no records match this criteria.

Comment: that is right this query get result. I can use this sample. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you don't need to specify global `$and`, the outermost object will act as if there was one.

The following query should work:

```
{
    "FirmId": ObjectId("5186224fdff7421bd4552f7f"),
    "$or": [
        {
            "Code": /^0/
        },
        {
            "Code": /^2/
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: $or should not be used when all clauses within it refer to the same field.

Comment: I agree with your comment.